# Is there a working combination of Arduino IDE + Ardublock?

Tags: arduino-ide

I'm trying to set up [Ardublock](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ardublock/), but the last release they have is from 2014 and in a recent Arduino IDE it fails when I try to upload the program to the Arduino board:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: processing.app.Editor.setText(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at com.ardublock.ArduBlockTool.didGenerate(ArduBlockTool.java:72)
   ....
```

I assume there is a different API in the recent Arduio IDE for copying the generated code into the editor. This is the block diagram I'm trying to upload. As you can see there are no libraries involved:

[image]

Is there a known combination of Arduino IDE and Ardublock which works? Or perhaps an addon similar to Ardublock which is maintained?

Comment: tinkercad has an online block editor in their circuits feature (drag out an uno to get to the editor).

Comment: @dandavis Looks pretty nice, too bad they don't seem to have support for subroutines. I struggle to find examples of programming environments with such a severe limitation, brainfuck interpreter and my first programmable calculator come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

I found that Ardublock project was forked on [Github](https://github.com/taweili/ardublock/releases), and the latest release indeed works with up-to-date Arduino IDE.